# Identifying Search Crawler

Tags: java, tomcat, web, web-crawler

I have a website which counts how many people visited that specific page, but i don't want to count when a search crawler is accessing them. Is there any way with java to identify if it is a crawler or a real user?
Using Java7 and tomcat

thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do this using a cms, so I would suggest looking at the data that the user provides when they request a page. They should send their browser information and you can use that to track users vs bots.

Comment: Check the `User-Agent` header of the incoming request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henry mentioned, you have to check `User-Agent` header of each request.

You can use this spider list: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/

Additionally you can make check for pattern whether it contains "bot", "crawler" etc. Please also note, that some bots can mask itself using usual user user-agent string.

This check must be very quick, so you need to create cache for crawler names. Or you can use Google Analytics, which I believe doesn't count web-crawlers.